# Platform Toolset 2008 with .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, c++-cli, clr

I am using VS 2012 as my editor and have a C++/CLI project using platform toolset V9 (VS 2008).  I've tried setting this to target .NET 4.0 via `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>` in the `Globals` section of my build file.  If I do this I get the following error message:

```
MSB8002: Specified platform toolset (v90) is not compatible with the targeted 
.NET Framework version (v4.0). Please set TargetFrameworkVersion to one of 
the supported values ('v2.0', 'v3.0', 'v3.5').
```

Although not supported, has anyone successfully been able to run .NET 4.0 in a v90 toolset?  Just want to ensure whether or not I really can't use .NET 4.0 because of this.  The reason for not just moving up the toolset to v100 is that the DLL that I am creating is being used in a third party application that is built using the v90 toolset.

Comment: When you use the v90 toolset then you are using the build tools that come with VS2008.  They don't know beans about .NET 4.0, that was later.

Comment: So in short not possible.  How bad is it to mix a vs100 DLL with a vs90 application.  The vs90 app will be calling into the DLL by dynamically loading via LoadLibrary.